# linear table to matrix format

Tags: text-processing, r

I would like to convert a linear table to a matrix format.

My input table looks like this and is called "linear_table.tab":

```
 transcript      ortho 
Transcript_1    ORTHO_1
Transcript_2    ORTHO_2
Transcript_3    ORTHO_3
Transcript_4    ORTHO_4
Transcript_5    ORTHO_5
Transcript_6    ORTHO_6
Transcript_7    ORTHO_5
Transcript_8    ORTHO_1
Transcript_9    ORTHO_4
Transcript_10   ORTHO_5
Transcript_11   ORTHO_2
Transcript_12   ORTHO_7
Transcript_13   ORTHO_8
Transcript_14   ORTHO_5
Transcript_15   ORTHO_2
Transcript_16   ORTHO_9
```

what I would like my matrix table to look like:

```
                           Transcript_1 Transcript_2    Transcript_3    Transcript_4    Transcript_5    Transcript_6    Transcript_7    Transcript_8    Transcript_9    Transcript_10   Transcript_11   Transcript_12   Transcript_13   Transcript_14   Transcript_15   Transcript_16
                Transcript_1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
                Transcript_3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_5    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
                Transcript_6    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_7    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_8    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_9    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_10   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_11   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_12   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_13   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_14   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_15   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                Transcript_16   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Here is my code using R:

```
  linear.table <- read.table("linear_table.tab", header=T, sep="\t")
  library(reshape2)
  dcast(linear.table, transcript~ortho, fill=0)
```

I get the following output in R:

```
              transcript ORTHO_1 ORTHO_2 ORTHO_3 ORTHO_4 ORTHO_5 ORTHO_6 ORTHO_7 ORTHO_8 ORTHO_9
        Transcript_1 ORTHO_1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_10       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_5       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_11       0 ORTHO_2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_12       0       0       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_7       0       0
        Transcript_13       0       0       0       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_8       0
        Transcript_14       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_5       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_15       0 ORTHO_2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_16       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_9
        Transcript_2       0 ORTHO_2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_3       0       0 ORTHO_3       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_4       0       0       0 ORTHO_4       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_5       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_5       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_6       0       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_6       0       0       0
        Transcript_7       0       0       0       0 ORTHO_5       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_8 ORTHO_1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
        Transcript_9       0       0       0 ORTHO_4       0       0       0       0       0
```

I am not sure how to proceed in this aspect using R.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat ortho.awk
NR > 1 {
  transcript = $1;
  ortho = $2;
  i = transcript;
  j = ortho;
  sub("Transcript_", "", i);
  sub("ORTHO_", "", j);
  imx[i][j] = 1;
}
END {
  for (i in imx) {
    for (j in imx) {
      omx["Transcript_"+i]["Transcript_"+j] = imx[i][j] == "" ? 0 : 1;
    }
  }

  printf("\t");
  for (i in omx) {
    printf "\tTranscript%d", i;
  }
  print "";

  for (i in omx) {
    printf "Transcript%d", i;
    for (j in omx) {
      printf "\t%d", omx[i][j];
    }
    print "";
  }

}
```

Idea is to populate a sparse matrix of 1's, then at the end fill it with 0's in the missing spots. Then print it out.

Comment: This just created a matrix with 0's only in it. It didnt include a 1.

Comment: I had `BEGIN{ FS = "\t" }` which was unnecessary, and I'm guessing your data didn't have tabs in it. Default FS for awk is whitespace which covers the tabs and non-tabs cases.

Comment: I just checked my data for tab-spaces. It still gave me the same output. 
I ran it using: 

´awk -f ortho.awk linear_table.tab´

Comment: I don't know then. Works for me. Are some non-printing characters in your data?

Comment: Nope. I just used the same table mentioned above. Not sure why it doesn't work for me :-(